# Slow MapEngine initialization when offline maps are on SDCard on Heremaps API (Android)

Tags: android, here-api

**I'm having quite a problem here:**

I want to have all Europe maps on my devices, but they don't have enough internal storage to have them all, so I'm using an SD-Card to store them.

The problem is when initializing the MapEngine [MapEngine.getInstance().init(...)] it takes a lot of time to load(until the OnEngineInitListener is executed) on older devices ( an Honor 5X [huawei KIW-L24] for the old device with android 6.0.1, but it's quite random, it usually takes about 23 seconds but sometimes it may take 2 seconds other it may take up to 1 minute and a half.

So, I tried to profile the app on android studio, and it gets stuck on the method com.nokia.maps.MapServiceClient.startServer, as shown on the attached image:

[Honor 5X Android Profiler Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2l6J.png)

I tried to factory reset the phone and even tried on other honor 5x phones, and the same problem is happening.

On logcat I get this error just before the OnEngineInitListener starts ( with WiFi connected, disconnected and with WiFi disabled):

```
24442-24442/net.gottsolutions.gps E/WifiManager: WifiServiceMessenger == null
```

On the other side, I tested the same app, and the same SDCard on a Nokia 4.2 (Android 9.0) and it took about 2 seconds to start that method.

So I decided to test your app (Here WeGo), with the Europe maps on SDCard, and I got a similar problem like on the GPS I'm developing.

**Video attached:**

https://youtu.be/YH7w9p0NeCs

Another problem is when initializing the MapEngine it is blocking the UI, even if it is started on another thread or background service.

The SDCard I'm using is a Kingston 32GB UHS I.

```
MapEngine.getInstance().init(sdkAppContextApplicationContext, error ->
                    {
                        if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE)
                        {
                            if (ISDKMapEngineListener != null)
                                ISDKMapEngineListener.onSDKReady();
                        } else
                        {
                            Log.e("MapEngine", "Failed to initialize MapEngine: " + error);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to pass context in turnOnWifi() like turnOnWifi(sdkAppContextApplicationContext) from MainActivity

```
wifi_manager =(WifiManager)sdkAppContextApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi_manager.setWifiEnabled(true); 
Thread.sleep(2000L);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it still not working correctly. It still gets stuck on that method shown on profiler.